# Django error : the format for date objects may not contain time-related format specifiers (found 'H')

Tags: python, django, date-formatting, french

I'm trying to display the date of birth in a French format, everything works fine on my PC, but when copying the same project on another computer and running it, I had this error under the date of birth (even if I changed nothing in the code) : `Django error : the format for date objects may not contain time-related format specifiers (found 'H')`

Here is my code :

**settings.py:**

```
# Format : day month year
DATETIME_FORMAT = ('d F Y')
```

**template.html:**

```
<body>
{% load i18n %}
{% language 'fr' %}
....
<td>{{ i.birthday|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT"|title }}</td>
...
{% endlanguage %}
</body>
```

Is the problem with the browser ? or should I install some library ?